# Scroll when hover - react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently, I have this menu, What I want to do is whenever we hover on the button with classname   "scroll-button-down" I want to scroll down the menu, but right now only the button is scrolling not all the menu.

This is my code so far:

```
 return (
      <div className="menu-wrapper">
        <div>
          <a className="menu-item">Pizza</a>
          <a className="menu-item">Hamburguers</a>
          <button>{"⌃"}</button>  
          <a className="menu-item">Guacamole</a>
          <a className="menu-item">Sushi</a>
          <button className="scroll-button-down">{"⌄"}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

css

  .scroll-button-down:hover {
    animation: moveMenushow 0.6s linear forwards;
  }

  @keyframes moveMenushow {
    100% {
      transform: translateY(-40%);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think that you can do this without JS. If you want to apply properties based on the state of a children, CSS is not the tool to choose (it's called cascading stylesheet for a reason). I think you will need to JS for this one.

Comment: Can you provide a very general example with js?? @chingucoding

Comment: I'll write that up as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Using JS, you can achieve this effect. Below is a code you can use to track the events. What element to scroll is not clear for me, so you will need to do that part yourself.

```js
let scrollToken = null;

function mouseEnter(direction){
  scrollToken = setInterval(function(){
    if(direction === "down"){
      // Scroll down, e.g. by using scrollBy
    }else{
      // Scroll up, e.g. by using scrollBy
    }
  }, 3);
}

function mouseLeave(){
  clearInterval(scrollToken);
}
```

```html
      <div className="menu-wrapper">
        <div>
          <a className="menu-item">Pizza</DropDownItem>
          <a className="menu-item">Hamburguers</DropDownItem>
          <button className="scroll-button-down" onmouseover="mouseEnter('down')" onmouseleave="mouseLeave()">{"⌃"}</button>  
          <a className="menu-item">Guacamole</DropDownItem>
          <a className="menu-item">Sushi</DropDownItem>
          <button>{"⌄"}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```